# internal server error when creating next build on ec2 using pm2

Tags: amazon-ec2, next.js, pm2

i'm working on a nextjs project, and deploy it with pm2 on ec2.
but when i command 'next build' on ec2 and connect to my nextjs project site, it returns internal server error.
[image]

this is my ecosystem.config.js file and i'm just using 'next build' command when i make a nextjs build.

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "my-project",
      script: "node_modules/next/dist/bin/next",
      args: "start",
      instances: 2,
      watch: false,
      autorestart: false,
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
      },
    },
  ],
};
```